# Winforms Dynamic size

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize

I have ma de a winform, that contains a tabControl (3 tabs, maybe more later).

In 2 of my tabs, I got a listBoxView.

The problem is, when I click on fullSize button, the tabControl doesn't change his size. That makes an awful window.

How can I define dynamic size of my tabControl, based on the winforms border size, and a dynamic size of my listBoxView based on tabControl size?

TabControl must adapt to form size, then pages in tabControl must adapt to tabControl size, and then, listBox in the pages must adapt to its pages size.

Here is the form :

```
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1313, 614);
    this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
    this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.tabPage1.PerformLayout();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dgCSV)).EndInit();
    this.tabPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.tabPage2.PerformLayout();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

And the tabControl with one of his pages :

```
 // 
        // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1288, 589);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // tabPage2
    // 
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.listBoxFiles);
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.buttonBottom);
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.buttonFront);
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.buttonDown);
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.buttonUp);
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label2);
    this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 25);
    this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
    this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
    this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1280, 560);
    this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
    this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

I tried with Parent.width, ClientRectangle, ClientSize.

I'm lost with all this properties and no one is successfull...

**After trippino answer :**

Indeed, a dock on the tabControl will resize him, but I can't do it on a listBoxView, because one of the element will just take all the page.

And Anchor do not resize elements, it will juste reorganise them to fit in the page.

Still not resizing like this :

```
    // 
    // tabControl1
    // 
    this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
    this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
    this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
    this.tabControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
    this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1313, 614);
    this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0; 

    // 
    // listBoxFiles
    // 
    this.listBoxFiles.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
    this.listBoxFiles.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top;
    this.listBoxFiles.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom;
    this.listBoxFiles.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
    this.listBoxFiles.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.listBoxFiles.ItemHeight = 16;
    this.listBoxFiles.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(185, 43);
    this.listBoxFiles.Name = "listBoxFiles";
    this.listBoxFiles.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
    this.listBoxFiles.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1040, 244);
    this.listBoxFiles.TabIndex = 42;



private void tabPage2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.buttonAucun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.buttonAucun.Location.X, this.listBoxFiles.Location.Y + this.listBoxFiles.Height + 10);
    this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.progressBar1.Location.X, this.buttonAucun.Location.Y + this.buttonAucun.Height + 10);
    this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.richTextBox1.Location.X, this.progressBar1.Location.Y + this.progressBar1.Height + 10);
    this.buttonEnregistrer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.buttonEnregistrer.Location.X, this.richTextBox1.Location.Y + this.richTextBox1.Height + 10);

    }
```

Since, buttonEnregistrer is on the bottom of my tabPage, I also tried :

```
    this.buttonEnregistrer.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.buttonEnregistrer.Location.X, this.tabPage2.Height -50);
```

But his will not retake it's original location.

Thank you.

Comment: No, When I have a 4 sides Anchor on all my elements or only on my listboxview, my listboxview will hide all other elements. How can I set location like "location (50, listboxiew.bottom.Location.y -10). It is an example, I don't know if it exists. So, for the moments, I only have 3 sides Anchor(left, top, right). So the width is bigger. It is a start.

Comment: You can set myControl.Location = new Point(X,Y) if you prefer. I suggest you to resize your form directly into the designer in order to see the behavior of anchors

Comment: I tried adding a size Changed event. But when I use the click on the button besides the close button, It grow normally(I have add an maximum size), but it will not take it's original size when a click again on it to shrink.

Comment: And for your question : when in the designer, it is the same as i describe. It takes all the space.

Comment: Yes the designer behaves as the runtime, I've suggested you to try there because you can 'play' with anchors and see the different behavior it makes. I can't help you since I don't see the code into the resize method

Comment: Edit the code with the sizeChanged method. Simple location with the element on the top. Problem is, with this, the design will not take it's original design if a change have been made. And also, richTexbBox1 will have a very small heigh(not proportional heigh). Weird.

Comment: I have tried `private void tabPage1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, tabPage1.Height - 50); }` and it works, maybe you have to change the value `50`?

Comment: for the richtextbox I think you have to pay attention at the anchor property

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34535/discussion-between-trippino-and-zaphod)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `Dock` property of the `tabControl` setting it to `Fill`. It should solve your issue.

[MSDN `Dock` Property reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx)

**EDIT AFTER DISCUSSION**: to anchor 4 sides you have to use :

```
this.listBoxFiles.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles
             ((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
```

Comment: Ok. This works for a tabControl, but what about the listBoxFiles? I must do it manually with (this.tabControl.width - value)?

Comment: You can use the same also for the listboxes. Try also the anchor property that can be very useful for your purposes

Comment: I can use Dock on my listBox only if it's the only element in the pages, because it will take all the page. And Anchor will only reorganize positions of my elements, this will not redimension my listBox.

Comment: yes it will resize the control, try to anchor on 3 or 4 sides and try to resize the form; you will see that it follows the resizing

Comment: Well, it seems not resizing. Or maybe I have to add 4 anchor for each elements?

Comment: you have to anchor the 4 sides for your listbox

Comment: I've updated the answer, also consider to use the designer to design forms without writing all of this code!

Comment: I use the designer, and the code I wrote is the autogenerated code. Also can you explained the code? Why use | and not ? Why all this ()? Thank you for your help.

Comment: this is the autogenerated code for a 4-sides anchorage. You have to use the | operator, otherwise you are overwriting the anchor value with the new assignments.